# checking if any method scheduled with Tkinter AFTER

Tags: python, tkinter

How do I check if there's any method scheduled with Tkinger AFTER method? I have one method that creates given number of squares randomly on a canvas(scheduled with AFTER method), and  another one that deletes the squares that are being clicked(this method is basically an event handler of each square.) And the last one deletes squares that aren't being clicked after certain time(like 2secs) and it is schedules with AFTER method. What I like to do is show a message box and display a message only when all the given number of squares are drawn and removed from the canvas. Because of there are times all the squares are removed but still few some squares left to be drawn, using find_all method doesn't work at all. If I use variable inside draw method and decrease it to 0, it's decreased to zero before the squares are shown and message box comes up at the wrong time as a result. So I'm looking for a way to find out if there's any method left to be executed in AFTER method list.

Comment: Is there any way to know if you have more squares left to draw?  Why not just `if counter == 0 and finished_drawing():` ...

Comment: Because squares are not drawn right away and scheduled with after method, variable is decreased to zero before all the squares are drawn. So if I use that condition, I get a message box at the wrong time.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it is possible using Tkinter methods, however, you can find such infos using Tk directly `widget.tk.call('after', 'info')` return a list of `after` pending subscriptions.

Here is a full example

```
import Tkinter

def foo():
    print "foo"

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.after(1000, foo)
#>u'after#0'
root.after(1000, foo)
#>u'after#1'
root.tk.call('after', 'info')
#>'after#1 after#0'
```